# Extracting the counter from the AVG aggregate in PipelineDB

Tags: pipelinedb

I have this continuous view:

```
=# CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW v AS
SELECT id::int, count(v::int) AS counter, avg(v) AS average
FROM mystream
GROUP BY id;
```

So I need the average, and the number of elements used to compute this average (`counter`). is there a way to extract this count from the AVG data structure, so I don't have to create a `counter` field ?

```
=# TABLE v_mrel0;
 id | counter | average
----+---------+---------
  1 |    2    | {2,30}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't. Internals of transition states are meant to be private. In you case of `avg(integer)` it's a two-element array, so you could potentially read the first element of the array, however this won't work with `avg` of other data types where the transition state is a byte array and there's no machinery to interface with it.

Is there a reason why having a separate `count` aggregate doesn't work for you?